# Automatically Created Documents don't have safety dialogs on close?

Tags: front-end

If I manually open a new DocumentNotebook in the front end using the GUI, and then I put input in the document, and then try to close the document, I get a safety dialog asking me whether I want to save the document:

[image]

If I create a new DocumentNotebook using the `CreateNotebook` symbol, put something into it, however, I can close the notebook and I don't get the safety dialog.  I want to force such automatically created notebooks to have a safety dialog.

At first blush, it looks like the contents I'm inserting into the created notebook are not inputs (no `In[47]:=` notation on the left).  So perhaps a better question is "How can I automatically insert input into an automatically created notebook?"  The key, here, is "automatically;" I want to do this without any manual interaction with the front-end GUI.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `ClosingSaveDialog` option in the created notebook:

```
nb = CreateDocument[TextCell[ExampleData[{"Text", "LoremIpsum"}], "Text"]];    
SetOptions[nb, ClosingSaveDialog -> True]
```

Comment: verified that adding the option to the inside of the call to `CreateDocument` did not work; it seems necessary to add the option after-the-fact with a call to `SetOptions`.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin I suppose adding whatever option works then.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin, yes I expected the option to work directly in `CreateDocument`. Not sure if it's this way by design or a bug.

Comment: @SimonWoods The fact that dialog is prompted doesn't seem be related to that specific option but to the fact that you are modifying the notebook. You can use `SetOptions[nb, Background -> Red]` and it will be equally good, except the fact of the red background ;).

Comment: SimonWoods no wait, @Reb.Cabin wants an automatic solution and it is such. Just rephrase it.