# Evaluating input cells in automatically created notebooks?

Tags: front-end

I've figured out how to insert `Input` cells and `Text` cells into an automatically created notebook (and, thanks to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112538/automatically-created-documents-dont-have-safety-dialogs-on-close), how to set the closing save dialog on).  Now I need to find a way to evaluate the cells in the document *without* manual intervention in the GUI, i.e., without going to the notebook and the GUI menu and selecting `Evaluate Notebook`.  I can see that there might be a security hole with such an option, still, I suspect it's doable, i.e., the front end GUI is calling some API when the user does the normal thing of clicking the `Evaluate Notebook` menu item, and it's very like Wolfram to expose everything the front end can do in an API / symbol to call.

[image]

Comment: What about `NotebookEvaluate`?

Comment: Very interesting: it brought the results of evaluation into the Creating notebook, rather than evaluating them in-place in the Created Notebook.

Comment: Verified that `NotebookEvaluate` with `InsertResults->True` does the job.  If you lift your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.